# Problem with understanding Multi-party security circuit for secure stable matching

Tags: reference-request, circuits, bipartite-matching, security

[image: Stable Matching Multi-part Circuit]I am reading the following paper:
MPCircuits: Optimized Circuit Generation for Secure Multi-Party Computation

[Paper Link](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/275.pdf)

I have following question:

We have two groups shown in the circuit. Why we call it a multi-party circuit?

Paper provides a comparison of its multi-part technique with the old 2 part based technique:

> In secure stable matching, the match list is computed while keeping
>   the  preference lists private to their respective owners. This problem
>   has  been studied in the recent literature [21], [22] where the secure
>   stable matching problem is reduced to a **two-party secure computation** 
>   scenario. Each individual XOR shares her preference list and sends it 
>   to two non-colluding servers who perform the secure computation. 
>   However, stable matching is inherently **a multi-party problem** and the 
>   assumption of two non-colluding servers may not be feasible in 
>   practice. To the best of our knowledge, we provide the first solution 
>   for multi-party secure stable matching.

The attached figure shows only how to input the preference list of group#1 and group#2. How can we perform n*n computation using the figure?
 Somebody please guide me. Zulfi.

Answer (score 0):

Stable matching involves finding a matching between two groups of people (group 1, say males, and group 2, say females).  Those are the groups that is referring to.

Comment: Circuit shows only two groups. But multi-party can mean more than two. How this two group circuit can work for multi-party i.e. more than 2?

Comment: @user2994783, the two groups is referring not to the parties that are computing the circuit, but to the matching problem (i.e., the input to the matching problem).

Comment: how the circuit uses two groups to do n*n computation?